# Secure PHP file uploading

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, security, file-upload

I'm trying to develop a file uploading module on our new site that allows you to upload *any* file to our servers. The uploaded file is uploaded to `/files`, in which the following .htaccess to prevent users from executing i.e a .php file:

```
<Files *.*>
ForceType applicaton/octet-stream
</Files>
```

This triggers the browsers download window (at least in FF and Safari), but is it safe to assume the file won't be run on the server using this method? If not, how would you implement such a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it safe to assume the file won't be run on the server using this method?

Kind of, but it depends on what other directives are present in your config; maybe there are other rules set up to allow PHP files to run. If the only way you're enabling PHP is by keying the PHP handler on file type, that should stop PHP executing.

However, stopping PHP executing is just one of your worries. If people upload files that contain active content, such as HTML or Flash — even if the filetype says it's an innocent image — they can gain control of other users' sessions on your site through cross-site scripting (XSS). See [Stop people uploading malicious PHP files via forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602539/stop/602904#602904) for some discussion of this.

A ‘download.php’ interface that uses Content-Disposition to always trigger the download box, coupled with storing the files under non-user-supplied filenames like ‘1234.dat’, is much safer.

Comment: While Content-Disposition: attachment triggers the download on all common browser, Opera, Safari, Konquerer will still open it in the context of the website, so the file has access to the session cookie.

Answer (score 3):

I think the safest thing is to restrict 100% web access to the directory, and have a script like `download.php` through which you pass a file id that then fetches the appropiate file and outputs it to the browser. However, I am pretty sure that what you have will work and is safe.

Answer (score 1):

I think you actually want this:

```
<Directory /path/to/files>
    SetHandler default-handler
</Directory>
```

What you have might work in practice, because the server is configured by default not to execute anything unless specifically told to do so, but it doesn't really guarantee that nothing will be executed. `ForceType` just sets the content type for static files (I'm not sure, but I doubt that it affects executable scripts).

Answer (score 1):

Seconding Paolo's answer, move your files directory out of the accessible path. You can then write the download.php script using PEAR's [HTTP_Download](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-download.intro.php) module to serve the files.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Paolo, his way is more secure.  There is always the issue of someone exploiting your PHP files to execute an uploaded one.  Bad Example:

```
include_once("/modules/".$_GET["module"].".php");
```

Where someone passed in `module=../Files/exploit`

Answer (score 0):

For maximum security, you shuold have the folder containing the uploaded files be mounted from a separate partition with the no-exec flag.