# Secure File Uploader ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I run an asp.net 2 application and am looking for a way to have users upload files from my web app. The main issue here is that I want this to be secure. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by secure? Secure can mean anything from [HTTP Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_authentication) to [TLS/SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Socket_Layer) data encryption.

If you want the connection to the server to be "secure", using SSL will encrypt the data transmitted between the client and the server.

Using e.g. HTTP Authentication, only the people who has the correct credentials will be able to access your pages, but people sniffing the network packets will not have a hard time viewing the data transmitted unless the connection is encrypted.

What I suspect you would want, if this should be an application with an above average security level, is to use [ASP.NET Forms Authentication](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240) along with SSL using https.

Comment: By security, I am concerned more with people uploading malicious files

Answer (score 0):

There is a [similar solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690108/how-to-prevent-every-malicious-file-upload-on-my-server-check-file-type)
But it is for php. You may rewrite the code for checking file type.