# PHP check if file is an image

Tags: php, image, file-upload, getimagesize

Is there a way to make sure a received file is an image in `PHP`?

Testing for the extension doesn't sound very secure to me as you could upload a `script` and change its extension to whatever you want.

I've tried to use `getimagesize` too, but there might be something more suited for that particular problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [uploaded file type check by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755192/uploaded-file-type-check-by-php) and [Security threads with uploads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061355/security-threats-with-uploads)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-extract-a-file-extension-in-php

Comment: @Pramod Just checking the file extension is precisely *not* enough.

Comment: Most secure way is to check mime type of the file.

Comment: @deceze I do agree with you Boss.

Comment: Not a duplicate, this asks for testing a specific main **media type** or in other words main media type group.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Native way to get the mimetype:

For PHP < 5.3 use [mime_content_type()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)
For PHP >= 5.3 use [finfo_open()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) or [mime_content_type()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)

Alternatives to get the MimeType are [exif_imagetype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) and [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php), but these rely on having the appropriate libs installed. In addition, they will likely just return image mimetypes, instead of the whole list given in [magic.mime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mime-magic.php).

While `mime_content_type` is available from PHP 4.3 and is part of the FileInfo extension (which is enabled by default since PHP 5.3, except for Windows platforms, where it must be enabled manually, for details see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php)).

If you don't want to bother about what is available on your system, just wrap all four functions into a proxy method that delegates the function call to whatever is available, e.g.

```
function getMimeType($filename)
{
    $mimetype = false;
    if(function_exists('finfo_open')) {
        // open with FileInfo
    } elseif(function_exists('getimagesize')) {
        // open with GD
    } elseif(function_exists('exif_imagetype')) {
       // open with EXIF
    } elseif(function_exists('mime_content_type')) {
       $mimetype = mime_content_type($filename);
    }
    return $mimetype;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to have been deprecated.

Comment: I just updated my answer. You can try this

Comment: Using exif_imagetype seems like what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: `finfo_fopen`, `getimagesize`, `exif_imagetype`, `mime_content_type` are not fully secure.. i took an html code  and save as png image.. after this i upload to server using  filereader Api in client side and in  server side  using functions  above write.

Comment: @Phoenix so there's is any better option to check whether the file is image file or not *before upload it* to server directory? thanks

Comment: `finfo_fopen()` should be `finfo_open()` - there is no `f` before `open`. "While `mime_content_type` is removed from PHP5.3" - I don't think it was ever "removed". It did appear to be (temporarily) deprecated, as many comments suggest, although there is no mention of this in the docs anymore. `mime_content_type()` is part of the [Fileinfo extension](http://php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php), which is enabled by default on PHP 5.3+ (except if you are on Windows, when you have to enable it)

Comment: Year 2018 PHP docs: `mime_content_type
(PHP 4 >= 4.3.0, PHP 5, PHP 7)` , not any mark of "deprecated" or such...

Comment: Year 2021 PHP docs `mime_content_type (PHP 4 >= 4.3.0, PHP 5, PHP 7, PHP 8)`, still no indication of "depreciated" notice.

Answer (score 93):

The **getimagesize()** should be the most definite way of working out whether the file is an image:

```
if(@is_array(getimagesize($mediapath))){
    $image = true;
} else {
    $image = false;
}
```

because this is a sample **getimagesize()** output:

```
Array (
[0] => 800
[1] => 450
[2] => 2
[3] => width="800" height="450"
[bits] => 8
[channels] => 3
[mime] => image/jpeg)
```

Comment: Yeah this was my gut feeling but I was looking for something that would be precisely suited to get the type of the file as you could trick this method. I've seen this done with Gifs (see here http://ha.ckers.org/blog/20070604/passing-malicious-php-through-getimagesize/).

Comment: Since `getimagesize` returns false on failure, this can be pared down to `$image = getimagesize($mediapath) ? true : false;`

Comment: `if($array = getimagesize($mediapath)) { // true and use the $array if required }`

Comment: Thanks for solution. I think putting @ before is_array is not neccessary in this case.

Comment: It will not work while uploading `swf` file instead of image. `swf`  file will return `array`.

Comment: `getimagesize()` is much slower. Better to use [exif_imagetype()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php)

Comment: PHP official docs recommend against this https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: @WilliamBingHua yeah, they do, but the warning was not there a few years back

Comment: `function fileIsImage($filepath){ 
return ( strpos(mime_content_type($filepath), 'image/') === 0 );

}`

Comment: [Caution:](http://php.net/manual/function.getimagesize.php) **Do not use** `getimagesize()` to check that a given file is a valid image.

Comment: NOT WORK ON SVG! TESTED!

Comment: Do not use getimagesize() to check that a given file is a valid image. Use a purpose-built solution such as the Fileinfo extension instead.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

Comment: Whether using `getimagesize` or `finfo_file`, as @Sheen mentions, additional checks are necessary.  See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690108/how-to-prevent-every-malicious-file-upload-on-my-server-check-file-type, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21525125/check-image-for-malicious-code-and-delete-it

Answer (score 13):

Using file extension and `getimagesize` function to detect if uploaded file has right format is just the entry level check and it can simply bypass by uploading a file with true extension  and some byte of an image header but wrong content.

for being secure and safe you may make thumbnail/resize (even with original image sizes) the uploaded picture and save this version instead the uploaded one.
Also its possible to get uploaded file content and search it for special character like `<?php` to find the file is image or not.

Comment: Isn't that a bit heavy? I'll look into it though.