# use getimagesize to test if an image

Tags: php, getimagesize

```
move_uploaded_file((getimagesize($_FILES[$desktop_fieldname_1280x800]['tmp_name']), IMAGETYPE_PNG), $desktop_filename_1280x800)
```

I want to check if it is an image before moving the file, is the code above possible? want to do something similar it should perform the test within that statement not outside.

Answer (score 0):

To check the type of the file you don't use getimagesize function, you might want to take a look [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408125/php-check-if-file-is-an-image)