# Wordpress plugin development - File upload: How to allow specified file types?

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, file-extension, file-type

Here is the code that allows uploading images to the root of the website. It is a submenu page in admin area that calls a function and the function body is bellow:

```
 <div class="wrap">
<h2>Upload files</h2><br><br><br>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" class="button" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>
</div>
<?php
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $target_dir = get_home_path();//wp_upload_dir();
    $target_file = get_home_path() . '/' . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        ?>
        <div id="setting-error-settings_updated" class="updated settings-error notice is-dismissible">
        <strong>File is an image</strong>
        </div>
        <?php
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
         ?>
        <div id="setting-error-settings_updated" class="updated settings-error notice is-dismissible">
        <strong>File is not an image</strong>
        </div>
        <?php
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
         ?>
        <div id="setting-error-settings_updated" class="updated settings-error notice is-dismissible">
        <strong>File already exists.</strong>
        </div>
        <?php
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
          ?>
        <div id="setting-error-settings_updated" class="updated settings-error notice is-dismissible">
        <strong>Your file is too large.</strong>
        </div>
        <?php
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != 
        "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
          ?>
        <div id="setting-error-settings_updated" class="updated settings-error notice is-dismissible">
        <strong>Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.</strong>
        </div>
        <?php
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
          ?>
        <div id="setting-error-settings_updated" class="updated settings-error notice is-dismissible">
        <strong>Sorry, your file was not uploaded.</strong>
        </div>
        <?php
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {                 
             ?>
        <div id="setting-error-settings_updated" class="updated settings-error notice is-dismissible">
        <strong>The file has been uploaded.</strong>
        </div>
        <?php

        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }

}
```

I want to allow these file types instead of images: .xml, .rar, .zip, .txt. I tried to change the function `getimagesize()` with the function `getfilesize()` and to change file extensions bellow the `// Allow certain file formats` comment. But it doesn't work. Do you have any idea what should I do to allow uploading these file types instead of file types that are currently enabled to upload?

Answer (score 1):

Very basically...

```
$allowed_extenstions=array('jpg','png','pdf','zip');

    $ext = pathinfo(esc_attr($_FILES['file']['name']), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if (!in_array($ext,$allowed_learning_extenstions))
            {
                echo "invalid_file_type";
                die();
            }

`
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. But if $check is set by getimagesize(), how to get $check if file is not an image?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408125/php-check-if-file-is-an-image. Should help you out on that one.