# Using JavaScript to add an attribute to all <input type="file">

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

My question is regarding a WordPress site. Using **JavaScript** or **jQuery**, on the entire front-end of the website, I would like to add the attribute `accept="image/*"` to all of the `<input type="file">`. Could someone please help me achieve this?

Comment: FYI: **Java** and **JavaScript** are completely different languages. And **jQuery** is a JavaScript library.

Comment: While this is possible, doing it through JS is not very reliable. Remember to always validate and virus scan any content uploaded to your server.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, _"Remember to always validate and virus scan any content uploaded to your server."_ - How would I go about doing that? Any good tutorial you could point me to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite trivial:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[type=file]")
 .forEach(file => file.setAttribute("accept","image/*"))
```

You will still need to check the type of file on the server too

For example

[Wordpress plugin development - File upload: How to allow specified file types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52752215/wordpress-plugin-development-file-upload-how-to-allow-specified-file-types)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works. _"You will still need to check the type of file on the server too"_ - How would I go about doing that? Any good tutorial you could point me to?

Comment: Depends on what the server language is.

Comment: I'm using WordPress, so I suppose it's PHP?

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 3):

**Using jquery in wordpress**

The following code uses `jquery` approach to solve your problem:

```js
jQuery(document).ready($ => {

  $('input[type=file]').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('accept', 'image/*');
  });

})
```