# What is the default value of `quality` parameter in `imagepng` function (`PHP`)?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, image-size, image-quality

I have used `imagepng` function in `PHP` to resize pictures. In the current code, I have not specified the `quality` parameter.

```
 imagepng($im_dest, $destfile);
```

But now I want to use it and increase or decrease the quality based on user's demand. To do that I need to know what is the default value of quality parameter in this function but unfortunately, I could not find that in the php.net website.

[description of imagepng function in the official website of php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php)

Do you know what is the `default` value? Does the `quality` parameter greatly affects the output size and quality?

One more question: Somewhere else, I resize the uploaded images (to their original sizes) to ensure there is not any malicious script attached to it. Is it a good practice or it is unnecessary?

Thank you very much for being helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While I was reading some of the user contribute notes I found this one and saying that the default quality is set to 6.

> from mhorne69 at gmail dot com
>
> from php source (gd.h):
>
> 2.0.12: Compression level: 0-9 or -1, where 0 is NO COMPRESSION at all, 1 is FASTEST but produces larger files, 9 provides the best
> compression (smallest files) but takes a long time to compress, and
> -1 selects the default compiled into the zlib library.  Conclusion: Based on the Zlib manual (http://www.zlib.net/manual.html) the default
> compression level is set to 6.

I hope that answers your question :)

Comment: thank you very much, It did. Do you know the answer of my second question?

Comment: I haven't done that yet  try checking out this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21525125/check-image-for-malicious-code-and-delete-it