# which type of files are forbidden to upload

Tags: php, file, upload, file-upload

I want to put a section in my site where people can upload things and I was wondering which type of files I should forbid for them to upload.

Comment: That depends on what service you want to offer. From one file type to every file type, it is all possible. E.g. dropbox.com obviously enables you to upload anything.

Comment: How do you determine the "type" of a file?  Based on what the untrusted distant user names the file?  This question applies to both white and black listings for files.

Comment: Host: "Okay Bob for $20,000 what is the user referring to in the above post when he uses the word 'things'? is it
a) doughnuts, b) files, or c) paper documents".
Bob: "Uhhhh, I have no idea, but I'm going to guess a) doughnuts"
Host: "Sorry Bob, that is the wrong answer";
*Audience sighs*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really depends on what you are going to do with the files. If you just store them, you could in theory accept even a collection of the world's worst computer viruses - as long as those files don't get executed.

As rogeriopvl suggests, better create a white-list of file types you want to allow.

Never rely on the MIME type that is sent with the browser. Always check the file type yourself, e.g. using [getimagesize()](http://de.php.net/getimagesize) if you want to allow only images.

A very good (but lengthy) discussion on the issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602539/stop-people-uploading-malicious-php-files-via-forms).

Answer (score 3):

You must not ask what type of files are forbidden (black-listing), but what types of files are allowed (white-listing).

So write down what files you want your users to upload and make sure that your app checks if the files are in the allowed format.

Primarily your list should not include:

- PHP files or any other scripting language file
- Executable files

Answer (score 2):

Checking the extension of the uploaded file isn't even half the story. There are file name syntax problems, type sniffing problems, script/plugin origin problems and more to worry about.

Making a file bucket that doesn't compromise the application is **hard** and not something to be undertaken lightly. As a starting point, consider serving files from a different [sub]domain to the file management application, and don't use a user-submitted filename as the basis for a filename on the server's filesystem.

(Please read the discussion at Pekka's link.)

Answer (score 1):

Anything that could exploit your website or application, this would be php files (obviously), any sort of executable files, and illegal things you don't want to be liable for hosting.

I would implement a white list of file extensions you want to allow people to upload and check based on their Mime type and file extension and write a policy about what files can and cannot be uploaded to your site.

I would also store an IP address and other relevant data along with the file, just in case you need to block someone from using or abusing your system. It's a lot of work but letting users upload files to your site isn't something that should be taken lightly.