# 'External Control of File Name or Path' security flaw

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I have a c# console application where in I need to write some data from database to a flat file. There output file path and the file name are configurable. I did like below:

```
using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(strWorkingOutputFile, false))
```

which is giving following error:

```
`'External Control of File Name or Path' security flaw.`
```

Basically, wherever we are giving a configurable path it's throwing that flaw. Any idea on how to resolve this?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Check the following SO Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595992/image-uploading-security-issues

Comment: Who is "it"? What tool are you using to check your code?

Comment: "It"'s a code security scan tool called 'Vera Code'.