# Codeigniter File uplaod

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

Hi I am trying to use the codigniter do_upload function below: 
But get this error: "**You did not select a file to upload.**" I do select a file and when i pass the name i can see the name but still can not upload...thanks in advance for the help.

```
function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $data = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        print_r($data);
        exit;
        //$this->load->view('clients_page', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        print_r($data);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're not naming your `<input type="file" />` the default `userfile`.  It would be nice to see your upload view also.

change this

```
$this->upload->do_upload()
```

to this

```
$this->upload->do_upload('audioRef')
```

Comment: <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="av" id="av" action="<?php echo base_url('upload/do_upload')?>"><br />
      <label for="audioRef">Audio reference (attach if available)</label>
      <input type="file" name="audioRef" id="audioRef" />
      <br /></form>

Answer (score 2):

> I do select a file and when i pass the name i can see the name but still can not upload

This is often because you've omitted to set your form to submit as `multipart/form-data`. Forms default to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which can't contain file uploads; in this case you just get the filename instead.

```
<form method="post" action="..." enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Incidentally,

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
```

if you must use filename extension to check file type (and it's inadvisable, but that's what CodeIgniter offers, unfortunately), please also allow `jpeg` and any other likely extensions.

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
```

If that uploads folder is within the webroot (you'll be serving files directly out of it), that's potentially a cross-site-scripting vulnerability. Unfortunately it is possible to upload files that look like images but in fact contain HTML, including `<script>`.

Doing user-uploaded-content in a safe way is **hard**. See eg [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602539/stop-people-uploading-malicious-php-files-via-forms) for background.