# Completely secure php file upload?

Tags: php, security, upload

I read other questions about subject. I know what I should not rely on.

I check file name with basename function and replce dots (except last one). Then i get file extension with explode function and check it with a blacklist defined by me. My question is; why any other control is necessary? Even if it is a malicious php code, (afaik) it will not be executed because of its extension is not php. There are already file size limitations in php settings. So, why?

Comment: Checking file type based on file name is incorrect and not reliable. User can give any name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop people uploading malicious PHP files via forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602539/stop-people-uploading-malicious-php-files-via-forms)

Comment: @ajrael I know user can change extension to anythnig but as i mentioned it won't work as original extension. I assume server is not misconfigured. Anyway Michal's answer showed me that any security measure is necessary. Thanks to him i learned it easy way. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 1000 answers why not, but imagine the following: I could upload a .htaccess file to make some other extensions being handled by PHP, thus I would be able to get around your "only .php files are executable". An very easy one :)

Comment: I think i can add htaccess to blacklist but i got your point (:

Answer (score 1):

Because you never know how creative attackers can be. As someone how is now taking a computer and network security course in the university I can say that the teacher gives me mind blowing examples every week on how easily one can misuse a small thing someone forgot to do by setting up the security for a random page\device.

Comment: Also not to forget - stressed people that are trying 'short cuts' and may cause (unknowingly) security risks. I did that to my own code once, and caused a C program to get segmentation faults - just by doing things it wasn't intended.

Answer (score 0):

this links is usefull:

1-https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload

2-http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/upload-forms-threat/