# PHP File Upload Code Injection

Tags: php, file-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop people uploading malicious PHP files via forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602539/stop-people-uploading-malicious-php-files-via-forms)

i found a way to clean the images from injected code by adding a very small transparent image to the uploaded image using PHP GD Library this will destroy the injected code (is there a better way ?).

but what about the other extensions if someone injected a code in a text file or whatever extension what can the attacker do in my server and how to prevent this type of code injection.

i'm writing a file upload script and i'm so confused in the security 
i searched a lot but nothing really helped me.

your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Set the file permission only to read on all uploaded files, that should help

Comment: "How to prevent this type of code injection?" Don't allow files to be uploaded.

Comment: Don't allow files to be uploaded !! it's a file upload center

Comment: @infinity could i do this with htaccess ??

Comment: I'm interested that your approach actually destroys the malicious code.  Preventing execution as illustrated below is great but taking the extra step to take it out seems really cool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the file permissions of all uploaded files to read using CHMOD like

```
<?php
  $filename = 'path/to/your/file.zip';
  chmod($filename, '744');
?>
```

Comment: thanks this really helped me you deserve a thousand vote simple and great