# Allow NGINX to write to folder /xibo/*

Tags: php

I'm currently installing Xibo for a few soon to be customers, but in the installation i need to provide a storage path for all files etc. I have Xibo running NGINX on Debian Wheezy.

it needs to write to: /xibo/storage. How could i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user that the PHP-FPM pool runs as should have write permission in that directory, and that directory should be in the `open_basedir` variable of PHP's configuration file.

Finally you should check out [stop people uploading malicious PHP files via forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602539/stop-people-uploading-malicious-php-files-via-forms/)  and [risks of a PHP image upload form](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32852/risks-of-a-php-image-upload-form/) before writing your upload form.

Comment: Please do NOT use or link to that site. It reports lot of wrong information, refer to [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/) there you can find links to some really great tutorials. Again: do not use w 3 s c h o o l s!

Comment: Is it also possible in my Vhost files??

Comment: Vhost or not should'nt matter here, as long as the Nginx user can write there and that PHP's open_basedir doesn't restrict access to that directory.